# Saving Canvas image into mysql db as blob datatype

Tags: php, html5-canvas

In My Project I got a canvas image and already sent to server, test.php, as shown below:

```
define('UPLOAD_DIR', '../uploads/');
$img = $_POST['canImg'];
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$data = base64_decode($img);
$file = UPLOAD_DIR . uniqid() . '.png';
$success = file_put_contents($file, $data);
if($success)
echo "success";
else
echo "failed";
```

My Question is, how to save the file in to blob mysql field?

Comment: take 2 fields in mysql  file_content (choose data type blob) blob , file_format varchar ,
save data , and when retriving back data , write blob feilds content in file_put_contents("xyz".file_format,file_content);

Comment: There are very few cases where storing images in databases is a good idea. Images are files and should be saved as that in the files system.

Answer (score 0):

Establish MySQL connection, create the image table with the field img_data and other fields as needed , then something like this:

```
 if (!mysqli_query($con,
     "insert into images (img_id, img_data) values (".
     (int)$img_id.",'".mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $img_data)."')")) 
 {
   // handle error
 }
```

Comment: You should recommend using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)  instead. Even `mysqli_real_escape_string()` has some security issues in certain situations.